# Really weird issue with ByteString socket

Tags: haskell

I had a weird problem with `ByteString` socket programming. I have minimized the issue to the following short scripts:

```
-- ByteString.hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Network.BSD
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

connectMud :: HostName
           -> String
           -> IO Handle
connectMud hostname port = do
          addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just hostname) (Just port)
          let serveraddr = head addrinfos
          sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol
          setSocketOption sock KeepAlive 1
          connect sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
          h <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
          hSetBuffering h (BlockBuffering Nothing)
          return  h

main:: IO ()
main =
     C8.putStrLn "connecting, please wait" >> connectMud "aardwolf.org" "4000"
     >>= BS.hGetContents >>= C8.putStrLn
```

and

```
--ByteString_Lazy.hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Network.BSD
import System.IO
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C8

connectMud :: HostName
           -> String
           -> IO Handle
connectMud hostname port = do
          addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just hostname) (Just port)
          let serveraddr = head addrinfos
          sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol
          setSocketOption sock KeepAlive 1
          connect sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
          h <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
          hSetBuffering h (BlockBuffering Nothing)
          return  h

main:: IO ()
main =
     C8.putStrLn "connecting, please wait" >> connectMud "aardwolf.org" "4000"
     >>= BS.hGetContents >>= C8.putStrLn
```

The only difference between these two short scripts is that one is using `Data.ByteString` and the other one `Data.ByteString.Lazy`. The lazy version works fine but the strict version does not seem to receive any output at all. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that it has to do with the differing behavior of the two `hGetContents` functions in question (the lazy version vs the strict version).

[The strict version](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.17/bytestring-0.10.8.1/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGetContents) "reads a handle's entire contents strictly into a ByteString." But you're trying to read from a stream, so the `EOF` is never encountered.

Compare with the behavior of [the lazy version](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.17/bytestring-0.10.8.1/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:hGetContents):

> Read entire handle contents *lazily* into a `ByteString`. Chunks are read on demand, using the default chunk size.
>
> Once EOF is encountered, the Handle is closed.

Comment: thanks! What a catch. The lazy ones work harder. Also I had to change to hSetBuffering to "NoBuffering" for my program to work properly.